# Bitbucket Server/shields.io Outline issue

Tags: markdown

I'm having a pretty trivial yet frustrating issue with Bitbucket.

I'm using a shield from http://shields.io/

The code below is not my shield specifically, but is basically the same:

[image: npm]

```
[![npm](https://img.shields.io/npm/v/npm.svg)](https://www.npmjs.com/ "npm")
```

The problem is that when I include this in the README.md of my Bitbucket repository, it appears with a narrow gray outline around the image:

[image]

I understand Atlassian has it's own subset of rules for Markdown, yet I cannot find any mention of handling image outlines in their documentation for using Markdown: https://bitbucket.org/tutorials/markdowndemo/overview#markdown-header-images.

I've tried adding a `<style>` block with the following CSS code:

```
.markup img {
    border: 0 !important;
    outline: none !important;
}
```

to the Markdown, but it appears as though that block was ignored entirely.

How I can get rid of this outline?

Answer (score 2):

I believe you're adding an empty link to the image, that's might be causing the issue. Try this:

`![npm](https://img.shields.io/npm/v/npm.svg)`

Should do the job.

Hope to have helped!

---

UPDATE

Look, I tried to reproduce your error, but on a [README.md](https://bitbucket.org/virtuacreative/tests/src) file that I created for that, the image looks fine:

[image: demo]

Comment: Ah, I'm sorry, the sample code did not have a url for the markdown link, but the one I'm using does have a url. I'm updating the sample code

Comment: Hmm... This is odd.. Can you post here your repo's url so I can take a look?

Comment: It's on a private bitbucket server and I would prefer not to do so. I'm not sure a solution to the question given the (now) accurate badge markdown is contingent on looking at the repository.

Comment: OK, no problem. With the url I thought I could inspect element and play around with the makup or css on my browser to see if something could affect it. You can try that yourself. I'm sorry, I'm afraid I can't help you then. Hopefully another user here on STO can give you a solution. Best of luck!

Comment: Thanks for the help! Oh, I should try to add a style block to remove outline/border! I'll modify the question based on that

Comment: Try to add the image with an html markup including the styles. If their markdown preserves html markup, should work!

Comment: @BTC I updated the answer. Unfortunately, I'm afraid I won't be able to help you, I couldn't reproduce your error. The only thing I thing might have caused your issue is if you haven't left a blank line between the previous paragraph and the image markup.

Comment: Thanks! I'm pretty sure based on some threads on Atlassian support boards that Bitbucket server and Bitbucket cloud are two different products, but thanks for testing it out!